# Get cart subtotal in woocommerce_before_calculate_totals hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I want to get cart contents total in woocommerce within `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` hook. So to achieve this I am using this code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'get_before_calculate_totals', 10 );
function get_before_calculate_totals( $cart_object ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    echo WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total(); //returns 0
}
```

But it returns 0 every time. So can someone tell me how to get cart total without currency within `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` hook?

Any help and suggestion would be really appreciable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` is used before any totals calculations, use instead the following that makes items subtotals calculations:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'get_subtotal_before_calculate_totals', 10 );
function get_subtotal_before_calculate_totals( $cart ) {
    $subtotal_excl_tax = $subtotal_incl_tax = 0; // Initializing

    // Loop though cart items
    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $subtotal_excl_tax += $cart_item['line_subtotal'];
        $subtotal_incl_tax += $cart_item['line_subtotal'] + $cart_item['line_subtotal_tax'];
    }
    echo '<p>Subtotal excl. tax: ' . $subtotal_excl_tax . '</p>'; // Testing output
    echo '<p>Subtotal Incl. tax: ' . $subtotal_incl_tax . '</p>'; // Testing output
}
```

Answer (score 0):

/* change this line
WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total()
with
$woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total()
because you have defined  global $woocommerce; for woocommerce object */

Comment: That's also returns price as 0. I had already tried that.

Comment: have you tried this also? WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal();