# Update Specific product subtotal in woo-commerce cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, e-commerce

```
foreach( $cart as $cart_item_id => $citem ) {
    if ( $citem['product_id'] == $gift ) {
        $item_id = $cart_item_id;
        $grp = $citem['data']->get_regular_price();
        //$woocommerce->cart->cart_contents[$cart_item_id]['line_subtotal'] = 1;
        $woocommerce->cart->line_subtotal($cart_item_id, '0');
        $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents[$cart_item_id]['line_subtotal'] = 1;
        //WC()->cart->set_session();
        
        //$woocommerce->cart->set_session();
    }                           
}
```

I can get access to cart details in "woocommerce_before_calculate_totals" hook.

But I can not manage to change the **line_subtotal** of a specific product.

Is there any way to do it using "woocommerce_before_calculate_totals" hook?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66167779/get-cart-subtotal-in-woocommerce-before-calculate-totals-hook/66168669#66168669

Comment: @7uc1f3r thanks but.. this is not working :(

Answer (score 0):

There is a way doing this using `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals`, but as you do that it would also affect the individual price of the product.

So if you choose to do this, you would have to reset the individual price of the product by then filtering `woocommerce_cart_item_price`.

But this is kind of wierd so I would try using `woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal`, if it works in your usecase.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal','new_cart_item_subtotal_filter', 10, 3);
function new_cart_item_subtotal_filter( $oldTotal, $cart_item, $cart_item_key){
    //filter...
    return $oldTotal;
}
```